# lucene java - filtering search "some," .txt "" and date of creation

Tags: java, lucene

Hello I did for a project using the "lucene" library in java, "this was the condition" we had to do a program that searched, the word family of a single word, of course we had to ignore the words of connection and so on
Now I should be able to condition the search according to the type of file I'm looking for
example: search "some," .txt "" and date of creation .. sort of filtering, the idea is that I'm not good at java and I would need a little help I've searched for google examples but no results: D thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest indexing the file type (file suffix like .txt .gif) as an additional field on your lucene document. 
Based on this you're able to search with for example a BooleanQuery for both fields.